Disable a user's sudo power only to lack of write access to iptables
Basically the title.
Context.
I'm the only admin of my PC, and I need to stop entering specific websites (reddit,youtube, etc)
So after setting specific domain bans to certain websites to iptables config, I need to not be able to modify the iptables but having sudo for everything else as to install new programs and keep customizing my linux system.
Let's say I have a 2nd user/person (with unknown password to me) with general sudo over the system so that I can use him to recover my power as a safety guard only, so that I can add more sites or disable the protection.
Please help me if you know how you'd pursue the operation customizing files/permissions, or if this's even viable.

Is this what you're trying to do?
